# Trying to link a SFML-app on fedora 25

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, sfml, fedora-25

**Hi everyone,**

I have some trouble trying to use the SFML library.I've tried different thing to make it work but always failing.

- I downloaded the official package but nothing worked when I tried to compile a basic program.
- I downloaded the version 2.4.1and put includes folder in */src/local/include/* and libs files in */src/local/lib/*. It was better than with the official package : I successfully got my .o. But the linking phase told me to install the jpeg library. So I did it but it was already installed on my system (Fedora 25) and doesn't changed anything. I saw on some forums that fedora use an other library to create jpeg picture : *libjpeg-turbo* which is a fork of the *libjpeg*. I have tried many thing to force my linux to use the libjpeg 8 instead of the one installed but without success.
- To make it work I tried the last solution : compile the SFML myself. So I downloaded sources, launch cmake and saw that it was missing lot something like 8 libraries to my laptop. After installed all those libraries I compile and install the SFML with the make target. Once it was done the compiling phase still working but the linking phase return me a obscure message for me (I translated it) :

> /usr/bin/ld: test: hidden symbol « __cpu_model » in
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/6.2.1/libgcc.a(cpuinfo.o) is
>   referenced by DSO
>       /usr/bin/ld : Failure during final link editing : Wrong value
>       collect2: error : ld has returned 1 execution status code

Do anyone know what's wrong ?

Comment: Can you describe what "nothing worked when I tried to compile a basic program" means? I have a guess — back at step 1, did you install `SFML-devel` or just `SFML`?

Comment: I have the same problem. I installed `SFML-devel` but the shared libraries require `libjpeg.so.8` which is not provided by Fedora. I would say the maintainer has not packaged it properly.

Answer (score 0):

SFML has issues with gcc 5.3 and newer. Currently GCC is version 6.3.1 in Fedora 25 repositories. You should apply [this patch](https://gitlab.peach-bun.com/pinion/SFML/commit/3383b4a472f0bd16a8161fb8760cd3e6333f1782.patch):

```
diff --git a/src/SFML/Graphics/CMakeLists.txt b/src/SFML/Graphics/CMakeLists.txt
index 6f02fb6..bdc84e7 100644
--- a/src/SFML/Graphics/CMakeLists.txt
+++ b/src/SFML/Graphics/CMakeLists.txt
@@ -148,6 +148,13 @@ add_definitions(-DSTBI_FAILURE_USERMSG)
 # when gcc is used; otherwise saving PNGs may crash in stb_image_write
 if(SFML_COMPILER_GCC)
     set_source_files_properties(${SRCROOT}/ImageLoader.cpp PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS -fno-strict-aliasing)
+
+endif()
+
+# see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gcc-5/+bug/1568899
+if(SFML_COMPILER_GCC AND BUILD_SHARED_LIBS)
+    message(WARNING "Applying workaround for https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gcc-5/+bug/1568899")
+    list(APPEND GRAPHICS_EXT_LIBS "-lgcc_s -lgcc")
 endif()

 # define the sfml-graphics target
```

If you do not want to download the SFML git repository, just open `src/SFML/Graphics/CMakeLists.txt`, locate the if conditional statement with the ImageLoader.cpp comment (line 150) and append the lines added by the patch. The end result should look like this:

```
# ImageLoader.cpp must be compiled with the -fno-strict-aliasing
# when gcc is used; otherwise saving PNGs may crash in stb_image_write
if(SFML_COMPILER_GCC)
    set_source_files_properties(${SRCROOT}/ImageLoader.cpp PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS -fno-strict-aliasing)
endif()

# see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gcc-5/+bug/1568899
if(SFML_COMPILER_GCC AND BUILD_SHARED_LIBS)
    message(WARNING "Applying workaround for https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gcc-5/+bug/1568899")
    list(APPEND GRAPHICS_EXT_LIBS "-lgcc_s -lgcc")
endif()
```